# UILongPressGestureRecognizer não funciona com meu UIImageView

Tags: swift

Estou tentando capturar o longo toque em minha imagem.
Assim posso mandar um ação ao em um longo toque.

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageRecord: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let longPressRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(addReconigzer(press:)))
    longPressRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = 1.0
    imageRecord.addGestureRecognizer(longPressRecognizer)
}

@objc func addReconigzer(press:UILongPressGestureRecognizer){
    if press.state == .began
    {
        print("oi amigo")
    }
}
```

Mas por algum motivo não está imprimido em meu console o "oi amigo" quando estou precionando a imagem por um determinado tempo. Alguém pode me informar onde estou errado ou o que deveria fazer para poder mandar executar a ação quando eu pressionar por um longo tempo minha imagem?

Aceito sugestões para poder fazer de outra forma, ja tentei fazer com botão mas também não conseguir alguém pode me ajudar ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É necessário habilitar a interação com o usuário já que a imagem não é um elemento de interação inicialmente. 
Isso pode ser feito tanto no storyboard/XIB como no código.

No Storyboard:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou

via código

```
imageRecord.userInteractionEnabled = true
```

Dica: Verifique se não tem nenhum outro elemento em cima da imagem que esteja bloqueando o longpress( O que pode ser a causa do botão não ter funcionado )

Answer (score 3):

```
imageview.userInteractionEnabled = true
```

Adicione esse code no seu **viewDidLoad**, creio que isso deve